# UK visa application checklist about family members remaining in home country

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas

On the checklist for the UK visa application, there's a provision stating the following:

Additional Information: Evidence of family members remaining in your home country whilst you travel.

I was wondering what that evidence could be? And I'm not married or have any children, and so the only family members I can mention having are my parents and my sister, none of whom are traveling with me. Do I even need to include anything for this, or would that be risky to my application?

Answer (score 1):

As a visa applicant, your task is to convince the UKVI examiner that you will return to your home country after your visit to the UK. The examiner will look for "ties" to your home country — things that would motivate you to return home — rather than violating the term of your visa, staying in the UK, and going underground in order to remain.

Things that suggest you would return home include (but aren't limited to) owning a home, having a continuing good job, having a spouse or children in the home country, having relatives in the home country, having investments or a business there, and so on.

You can't create a spouse or children, but family ties have some weight. The existence of your parents and other close relatives there should be included in your application. If you have no relatives in the UK, I'd mention that as well.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm a permanent resident of the US but my parents live in Saudi Arabia and I'm unmarried. No family in the UK at all so I hope I don't have to make any declarations about either.

Comment: You're welcome. The issue for UKVI is to be convinced that you'll leave the UK after your visit. I think permanent residence in the US will appear valuable, even 'though the US isn't your original "home country." And as I noted, if you _don't_ have family in the UK, that fact is worth mentioning.